# What is the latest Facebook PHP API?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Seemingly it supposed to be `https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/`. However, I am suspicious either it so because `getLoginUrl` method generates not the type of URL that is described in `http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/`.

So I was wondering which of these is outdated?

Comment: Theres only one url so cannot say which is outdated. That is the what facebook says is the official api so it must be upto date. I don't have any experience with the API yet so I cannot say definitely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP SDK that you linked is up to date. It is a client for the various Facebook APIs, including the Graph API, the "old" REST API, and others. Right now, getLoginUrl() does generate a URL that has been used for longer than the OAuth documentation has existed, but the end result will be the same for you. If you do have a problem with that login URL for some reason, you're free to implement authentication any way you like by replacing or extending the existing SDK logic.

Remember, APIs and SDKs are not the same thing. The PHP SDK is just one API client. Everything in the official FB docs should be considered up-to-date, as they've all been revamped this year.

Answer (score 1):

OAuth based authentication and Graph Api for data are the latest ones.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

see this also:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/

Comment: So in other words, I should not use the php-sdk and instead use the method described in the documentation?

Comment: I would recommend going with the new ones, since facebook is going to deprecate the old apis and FBML very soon. See this also ..http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/